# Interface builder's not showing the navigation controller's navigation bar inside a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I recently switched to Xcode 4 from 3.2 and so far everything's been fine. There's one thing that's driving me nuts for the last hour or so. In my main window xib, I have a Tab Controller with 4 tabs. Three of them are regular UIViewControllers, but one is a UINavigationController.  The problem is that with Xcode 4's Interface Builder, I can't see the navigation controller's navigation bar. I just get a window that says "Address List Table View Controller inside of a Contacts Navigation Controller". Why doesn't Xcode show the nav bar? In Xcode 3's IB I could see it, add buttons, change the title, etc. I can't seem to do that here.

If you watch this video, the person drags a UINavigationController into the tab bar and you see the bar just fine.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSBK8Zz6O4M

I set the custom class to my ContactsNavigationController, and the changes I make in the nav controller's xib don't reflect in the tab controller like the regular view controller's xib changes do.

So, I'm a little confused. I'm not new at this, I've been at Xcode programming since Day One, but I'm quite lost as to why the nav bar doesn't show up in the tab controller's view, and why when I set the nav controller to my custom class (even set the nib file), it doesn't work. Everything else does.

Comment: try selecting the navigation controller in the scene hierarchy to the left in IB.  then click on the attributes editor in the right.  the top section should be called "Simulated Metrics".  are all of those set to "Inferred"?

Answer (score 1):

i just had this issue on an older project. i changed the size in the properties for the root view controller and this seems to have flushed interface builder, including it showing the navigation bar on views that were linked to nav controllers, but in IB had no nav bar displaying